# Magento 2.3 How to Auto Select Swatch Option Values if Only One Exists in Product View

Tags: magento2.3.1, product-page, color-swatches

I'm trying to have swatch option values selected on the Product View page if only one value exists.

also, I have tried this reference but not working for me 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176243/68695

like :

[image]

**Note**: when one swatch value available then this value is auto selected and *remove validation message*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have solved following way..

open below file if exist otherwise overide

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js

Make changes in the `_RenderControls()` function as shown below.

**after end of this function add like this code**

```
var swatchLength = $('.swatch-option.color').length; // if color attribute 
  if(swatchLength == 1){
     if($('.swatch-attribute').hasClass("color")){
        $('.swatch-option').first().trigger('click');
      }
  }
```

[image]

after run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: I am using size attribute as dropdown and this code is not working help

Answer (score 0):

add this code anywhere on product page

```
<script>
 require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
     $(document).on('swatch.initialized', function() {
        var swatchLength = $('.swatch-attribute').length;
         console.log("attribute",swatchLength);
        if(swatchLength >= 1){
            $('.swatch-option').first().trigger('click');
            $('.swatch-option').first().trigger('mouseover');
        }
    })
 });
</script>
```