# Pre select configurable product in magento 2 PDP

Tags: magento2

Hi I want whenever someone opens configurable product page with size and color the first child should be preselected

how to achieve this I am using latest Magento 2 version

Answer (score 0):

please follow the below link,
you need to change this as per your attribute,
it working fine for me

https://meetanshi.com/blog/auto-select-first-child-product-of-magento-2-configurable-product/

Comment: already tried this not working

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to override this file in your custom theme as below:-

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js
```

Change **`_RenderControls()`** function

After the end of this function add the below code:

```
var swatchLength = $('.swatch-option.color').length; // if color attribute 
  if(swatchLength == 1){
     if($('.swatch-attribute').hasClass("color")){
        $('.swatch-option').first().trigger('click');
      }
  }
```

And then you need to run below command:-

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Also, you can get more information here:-

**https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/278663/85907
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/129887/85907**

Hope this helps you

Thanks ...

Comment: I am using size attribute as dropdown and this code is not working help