# Magento 2.3.2 Single color variation auto selected on product list page

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-list, swatches, color-swatches

Magento 2.3.2 Single color variation auto selected on product list page, i have added this code in swatch-render.js after container append but it is selecting on all products instead of selecting only visible products so if you have 500 to 600 products in this category then it will trigger this action 500 or 600 products instead of 18 which are currently visible.

```
$('.product-items .product-item:visible').each(function () {
                    // console.log("item count ",$('.product-items .product-item:visible').length);
                        var index = $(this).index();
                        var itemcount=$(this).length;
                        var text = $(this).find('.swatch-attribute.color').find('.swatch-attribute-options').children().length;
                        //console.log(text);   
                        if(text==2) {
                            console.log(text);  
                            $(this).find(".swatch-option.color").trigger("click");  
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163487/how-to-auto-select-swatch-option-values-if-only-one-exists-on-magento-2-1-produc/176243#176243 this solution took me closer to what i want to achieve but when i have both color and size only one it selects only size instead of both .

Answer (score 0):

use This Code in your swatch-renderer.js
 `var swatchLength = $('.swatch-option.color').length; // if color attribute  if(swatchLength == 1){ if($('.swatch-attribute').hasClass("color")){ $('.swatch-option.color').first().click(); $('.swatch-option.color').prop('disabled',true);  } }`